# Binary Representation of Integer.MIN_VALUE

Tags: java, binary

The binary representation of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in Java is `10000000000000000000000000000000`.

Why wouldn't it be `10000000000000000000000000000001` instead, since the addition of one to its two's complement would be larger than `10000000000000000000000000000000` by one?

Comment: I'm not quiet understand the final statement in your question: "since the addition of one to its two's complement would be larger than 10000000000000000000000000000000 by one?"

Answer (score 6):

`int` in Java is a signed 32-bit number, meaning that the 32th bit, like you said, represents the negative number, in decimal, `-(2^31)`, and in binary:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
^ → "negative bit"
```

But the remaining 31 bits are still "positive" bits in a signed system, so:

```
10000000000000000000000000000001 → -2^31 + 1
```

And `-2^31 + 1` is bigger than `-2^31`.